# Django: New field not showing up in form after adding it to model

Tags: python, django, forms, model

After adding a new field to my model, it doesn't show up in the form.

I have been working on this django app and have extended the already existing User model with my own UserProfile model with extra fields. Recently, I have decided to add an extra field to the UserProfile model (profile_type). I added it to the model and included it in its corresponding form, and ran makemigrations and migrations. I then tried inserting an initial value to this field in my views and found out that it is not showing up in the form through print(), however, all the other fields are.

My UserProfile model

```py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='userprofile')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 45)
    country = models.CharField(max_length = 45)
    birthdate = models.DateField(null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    profile_type = models.CharField(max_length = 6)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile = UserProfile(user=instance)
        profile.save()
```

My UserProfile forms (UserProfileForm contains the fields necessary for sign up, AdditionalUserProfileForm is the rest)

```py
class UserProfileForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User    
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserProfileForm, self).save(commit=True)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()
        return user

class AdditionalUserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    profile_type = forms.CharField(max_length=6)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('gender', 'city', 'country', 'birthdate', 'phone_number', 'profile_type')
```

My Sign Up view (I want to add the value to profile_type manually upon instantiation

```py
@transaction.atomic
def signup_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
        initial = {
            'profile_type': 'user'
        }
        additional_user_profile_form = AdditionalUserProfileForm(request.POST, initial=initial)
        valid = user_profile_form.is_valid() * additional_user_profile_form.is_valid()
        if valid:
            user = user_profile_form.save()
            for field in ['gender', 'city', 'country', 'birthdate', 'phone_number']:
                setattr(user.userprofile, field,
                        additional_user_profile_form.cleaned_data.get(field))
            user.userprofile.save()
        return redirect('login')
    else:
        user_profile_form = UserProfileForm()
        additional_user_profile_form = AdditionalUserProfileForm()
        context = {
            'user_profile_form': user_profile_form,
            'additional_user_profile_form': additional_user_profile_form,
        }
        return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', context)
```

Printing out the form fields in the terminal doesn't show that profile_type is one of them. I saw on some thread that it's a bug but the fix did not work for me. It was something about changing the get_fieldsets function in contrib/admin/options.py. Hope this gives you a hint. Thank you!

Comment: Did you run makemigrations and migrate?

Comment: Yes I have, and it turned out I had to add the field to the template, otherwise it wouldn't be considered as part of the form, even if it is included in the form class, my bad.